Is there a way to DVC import a private https git repo?
I am trying to perform a DVC import on a private https git repo. I am using a git credential manager to store the git credentials for the repo as recommended here. When I perform the dvc import command
dvc import https://gitlab.com/<repo>.git <directory>

I get an error saying:
ERROR: failed to import '<directory>' - SCM error: Failed to clone repo 'https://gitlab.com/<repo>.git' to '/tmp/tmp3xrgnmfjdvc-clone': ('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(71 bytes read)'

Any idea what might be the cause of this?
I have tried dvc importing various public repos and have no trouble.

Try directly git clone https://gitlab.com/<repo>.git to init credential manager. Or switch to ssh protocol and use ssh keys to avoid password prompt.

@phd I have tried cloning beforehand to initialize the credential manager, it still seems to have the same outcome.

There should be more than just one-line error; can we see the entire text output from git clone?
